# Why does it look like my androidbutton is compressed in width?

Tags: android, button, programmatically-created

I want to add multiple Buttons in my activity programmatically. That works fine so far, but it looks like my button is compressed in width. The button has a background image that is 20*20px and im using WRAP_CONTENT for width and height. Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        LinearLayout layout;
        Button buttonDel;

        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        buttonDel = new Button(this);
        buttonDel.setId(i);
        buttonDel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttondelete);
        buttonDel.setLayoutParams(params);

        layout.addView(buttonDel);

    }
```

And the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.developer.cardz.ListOfAllWordsActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linLayout">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: does it has any text inside them? If your button had any text on them, then those would be considered as "content" so it may compress image regarding to text.

Comment: can post the screenshot of your output?

Comment: aaah right, the text is the problem. I should use ImageButton... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it has any text inside them? If your button had any text on them, then those would be considered as "content" so it may compress image regarding to text.

Answer (score 0):

Let me do some suggestions.

Your code is more efficient this way:

```
    LinearLayout layout;
    Button buttonDel;

    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        buttonDel = new Button(this);
        buttonDel.setId(i);
        buttonDel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttondelete);
        buttonDel.setLayoutParams(params);

        layout.addView(buttonDel);
    }
```

And `layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`is not needed, since you have it on your XML.

Could you show the R.drawable.buttondelete? If it's a png9, it's normal it is shrunk. Try putting some text to the button.

Comment: Sorry, i cant upvote. It says i need more "reputation".

Comment: Accept the answer, you should be able to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed Button to ImageButton. That solved the problem. Thanks to all who have commented!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you want to continue with *Button*, change

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

to

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);`

where `(100, 100)` is your desired button *width* and *height*.